# Can I start a Jupyter notebook using a Spyder kernel?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have been able to start a remote ipython console using 'python -m spyder_kernels.console' and connect to it using Spyder on my local machine. However, this just gives me a console. I want to get a notebook running remotely and connect to it using Spyder. I understand the Spyder kernel is different and has several modifications. My question is, can I start a remote Jupyter notebook, using a Spyder kernel, and then connect to this notebook from inside my local Spyder? I have the Spyder notebook plugin installed. The idea is that since the notebook is started using a Spyder kernel, Spyder should be able to interact with it and the Variable Explorer should work.

PS: I know it should be possible to start a Jupyter notebook with the Spyder kernel, because that's exactly what the notebook plugin for Spyder does inside of Spyder. I just want the ability to start this notebook remotely and then connect to it.

Comment: Question is not very clear imo... Are you trying to connect spyder to a remote kernel, or have you already accomplished that?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. I have been able to connect to a remote kernel. What I want is to startup a remote notebook using the spyder kernel, and then use the remote notebook from inside a local spyder install using the spyder-notebook plugin. I'll be happy to clarify further if there's still confusion.

Comment: So you're essentially just looking for a way to **start** a server-side kernel to connect to from client-side? So the question is something akin to "how do I remotely execute a `jupyter notebook` script from a client"?